# undefined is not an object(evaluating this.props.navigator.push)

Tags: react-native

I have two page i.e sign in page and a payment page.
I am trying to navigate to payment page on tap on SignIn button, but i am getting error undefined is not an object(evaluating this.props.navigator.push)

The code is as below:

```
import React, {
StyleSheet,
Text,
View,
TextInput,
Component,
Alert,
Navigator
} from 'react-native';

var Button = require('react-native-button');
import Payments from '../payments'


class Signin extends Component{


 onSubmitPressed(){
    this.props.navigator.push({
        title: 'secure Page',
        component: <Payments/>

    });


  };

render() {
return(

 <View style={styles.container}>
<View style={styles.Inputview}>
<TextInput id='user' style={styles.input}
placeholder={'Username'}
/>
<TextInput id='Password' secureTextEntry={true}
placeholder={'Password'}
onChangeText={password => this.setState({password})}
/>
</View>

<View >
 <Button style={styles.Register}  
 onPress={(this.onSubmitPressed)}>
  Sign In
  </Button>
 </View>
 </View>
 )
  }
 }


 export default Signin


If any one let me know how to solve this issue??
```

Comment: Can you show your `Navigator` component and your `renderScene` method?

Comment: @NaderDabit  i have not added any navigator component here i have only added code to signin page as given above in payment.js i have only message called welcome

Comment: @animesh please provide some information about your react-native version you are using

Comment: @MarcelSchulze react-native@^0.22.2

Comment: i am  following this example, https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2015/09/using-navigator-routes-in-your-react-native-application/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to set up your Navigator and initial route as the entry point as opposed to a regular component. Try something like this:

(Also set up a working example [here](https://rnplay.org/apps/iKx2_g))

https://rnplay.org/apps/iKx2_g

```
class App extends Component {
  renderScene (route, navigator) {
    return <route.component navigator={navigator} />
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Navigator
        style={styles.container}
        renderScene={this.renderScene.bind(this)}
        initialRoute={{component: SignIn}}  
      />
    );
  }
}

class SignIn extends Component {
  _navigate () {
    this.props.navigator.push({
        component: Payments
    })  
  }
  render () {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Hello from SignIn</Text>
        <Button onPress={this._navigate.bind(this)} />
      </View>
    )
  }
}

class Payments extends Component {
    render () {
    return (
      <Text>Hello from Payments</Text>
    )
  }      
}
```

Comment: as Nader Dabit mentioned example is the correct way to pass navigator object and render individual component :) also bind the method in constructor which should be called in onPress of button :)

Comment: I am getting error undefined is not an object( evaluating this.props.navigator.push')

Comment: @Nader Dabit can you please put a glance on below link  :- 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44517782/undefined-is-not-an-objectevaluating-this3-props-navigation

Answer (score 5):

First you need to bind the `this` to the function `onSubmitPressed`. And make sure that you have passed navigator object to this component on the `renderScene` function of the navigator.

```js
// binding this to onSubmitPressed
<Button style={styles.Register}  
   onPress={this.onSubmitPressed.bind(this)}
 >
    Sign In
</Button>

// binding this to on SubmitPressed using arrow function 
<Button style={styles.Register}  
   onPress={() => this.onSubmitPressed()}
 >
    Sign In
</Button>
```

Comment: can you please let me know how to pass navigator object to this component in render scene

Comment: here is a simple tutorial explaining the basics of Navigator component and how to pass props to components from navigator: https://medium.com/@dabit3/react-native-navigator-navigating-like-a-pro-in-react-native-3cb1b6dc1e30#.5reoa2bdb

Comment: @animesh <YourScene title="YourScene" navigator={navigator}/> linke this