# Undefined is not an object( evaluating this.props.navigator.push')

Tags: android, react-native

I am learning `react-native` programming for android application. I am trying to start second screen on pressing on `TouchableOpacity`. I am using `navigator` for same.

I am getting this error `undefined is not an object( evaluating this.props.navigator.push')`

I have checked a lot of threads [React Native, NavigatorIOS, undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.navigator.push')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31304017/react-native-navigatorios-undefined-is-not-an-object-evaluating-this-props-n) [undefined is not an object(evaluating this.props.navigator.push)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37441365/undefined-is-not-an-objectevaluating-this-props-navigator-push) but did not work for me. I am not sure what I am doing wrong here, can anyone help me . Thanks in advance.

> index.android.js

```
/**
* https://github.com/facebook/react-native
* @flow
*/

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, Text, View, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, ToolbarAndroid, StyleSheet,Container,ScrollView, Navigator } from 'react-native';


class App extends Component {
  renderScene (route, navigator) {
    return <route.component navigator={navigator} />
  }
  render() {
    return (
        <Navigator
          style={styles.container}
          renderScene={this.renderScene.bind(this)}
          initialRoute={{component: LoginComponent}}
        />
    );
  }
}

class LoginComponent extends Component {

  _navigate () {
      this.props.navigator.push({
          component: DashboardComponent
      })
  }

  render() {
     return (
          <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'column'}}>

            <ToolbarAndroid title='LOGIN' titleColor='white'
                onIconClicked={() => this.props.navigator.pop()}
                style={styles.toolbar}/>

            <View style={{padding:10}}>

              <TextInput style={{height: 40, borderColor:'gray', borderWidth: .5}}
                  placeholder="Email address" underlineColorAndroid='transparent'/>

              <TextInput style={{height: 40, borderColor:'gray', borderWidth: .5}}
                  placeholder="Password" secureTextEntry={true} underlineColorAndroid='transparent'/>

              <TouchableOpacity style={{ height: 40, marginTop: 10 , backgroundColor: '#2E8B57'}} onPress={this._navigate.bind(this)}>
                  <Text style={{color: 'white', textAlign: 'center', marginTop: 10, fontWeight: 'bold'}}>LOGIN</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
       </View>
     );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    toolbar: {
     backgroundColor: '#2E8B57',
     height: 40,
     fontFamily: 'noto_serif_regular',
    },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('ExampleOne', () => LoginComponent);
```

> second.android.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class DashboardComponent extends Component {
  render() {
     return (
       <Text>Hello!</Text>
     );
   }
 }
```

Comment: Your code is looking fine, try this `onPress={() => this._navigate()}` on your `TouchableOpacity`.

Comment: I am trying to call second component which is in another file. When I am trying to call then I am getting an error `can't find variable: DashboardComponent `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You register wrong component in `AppRegistry.registerComponent`, it should be `App` instead of `LoginComponent`

Navigator component need to be render first, then it will render and pass navigator prop down to it scenes.

Comment: +1 I am trying to call second component which is in another file. When I am trying to call then I am getting an error can't find variable: DashboardComponent

Comment: you need to import the `DashboardComponent`, ie `import DashboardComponent from './DashboardComponent` assuming the `DashboardComponent.js` is same folder with your `index.android.js`

Comment: Now I am getting an error Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function but got: object. Check the render method of `Navigator`.

Comment: I think you forgot to export your `DashboardComponent`, just add `export default DashboardComponent;` in your `second.android.js`, then import it as `import DashboardComponent from './second';` in your `index.android.js`

Comment: there is some lagging while transition.. What could be the reason for this

Comment: logging, emulator type, turning on debug js remotely, debug build, rendering while transitioning may cause lagging. For more detail, you can refer to [https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/3049](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/3049) for more detail